# Bash only get the first matched result when use regex

Tags: regex, bash, match

There's a string example

```
"j2sdk/1.8.0_25-static j2sdk/1.8.0_45 j2sdk/1.8.0_p120 j2sdk/1.8.0_40 j2sdk/1.8.0_51"
```

I want to find the ones matched with format j2sdk/1.8.0_xxx, but xxx only with digits, here, I want below strings be matched

```
j2sdk/1.8.0_45 
j2sdk/1.8.0_40 
j2sdk/1.8.0_51
```

I wrote below code, but when run, it only get the first matched `j2sdk/1.8.0_45`, anything wrong with my code?

```
avail_versions="j2sdk/1.8.0_25-static j2sdk/1.8.0_45 j2sdk/1.8.0_p120 j2sdk/1.8.0_40 j2sdk/1.8.0_51"

patern='j2sdk\/1\.8\.0_[0-9]+\s+'

if [[ $avail_versions =~ $patern ]];then
        echo matched
        echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
        echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}

fi
```

The results is that `BASH_REMATCH[0]` is `j2sdk/1.8.0_45`, `BASH_REMATCH[1]` and `[2]` are empty

I expected I can get them in `BASH_REMATH[1]`,`BASH_REMATH[2]`,`BASH_REMATH[3]`.

Is there other way in Bash I can get expected matches.

Thanks

Comment: You need to get multiple matches, not look for a content in non-existing groups (your pattern hasn't got any groups, only Group 0, the whole match, is initialized). See [this demo](https://ideone.com/ifSqx6).

Comment: Check if [this snippet with `grep`](https://ideone.com/ifSqx6) works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I split the input at spaces and add back the space after each word.

```
for s in $avail_versions ; do
    s="$s "
    if [[ $s =~ $patern ]];then
        echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
    fi
done

j2sdk/1.8.0_45
j2sdk/1.8.0_40
j2sdk/1.8.0_51
```